# QML Repeater inside of a DelegateModel

Tags: delegates, qml, repeater

I'm attempting to access the model on a Repeater found within a DelegateModel without success.

Using just a 'Text' element in the Repeater.  The Repeater's model is accessible and the Text does discover the 'modelData' as expected

However, When I use my 'Tile' element, which has drop and drag favor.  The Repeater model  is inaccessible and my 'Tile'>'text' is unable to use it

...

```
###########  FruitTile.qml #########################
import QtQuick 2.6 

Rectangle {
id: root
required property Item dragParent

signal pressed
signal released
signal clicked

property int visualIndex: 0


anchors {
   // horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   // verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
}
radius: 3


MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    drag.target: root
    onClicked: root.clicked()
    onPressed: root.pressed()
    onReleased: {
        parent.Drag.drop()
        root.released()
    }
}

 Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
 Drag.source: root
 Drag.hotSpot.x: root.width / 2
 Drag.hotSpot.y: root.height / 2

states: [
    State {
        when: mouseArea.drag.active
        ParentChange {
            target: root
            parent: root.dragParent
        }

        AnchorChanges {
            target: root
            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
        }
    }
]
}

###########  DelegateTestModel.qml  ###############
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.2

Rectangle {
id:rootTest
width: 600; height: 100

GridView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: visualModel
}
DelegateModel {
    id: visualModel
    model: fruitDrinksModel
    delegate: DelegateDelegateModel { }    
}

ListModel {
    id: fruitDrinksModel

    ListElement {
        name: "Apple Cider"  
        color: "blue"
        modelIndex: 0  
    }
} 
}
#######################  DelegateDelegateModel.qml  #######################

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

ColumnLayout {
Text { text: "Fruit Drink Name: " + name}
Repeater {
    model:  fruitModel  

    FruitTile {
        anchors.top: modelyData.bottom
        dragParent: rootTest
        width: 100; height: 40
        border.width: 1
        color: "yellow"
        Text { text: "Fruit Name: " + modelData}
        //Text { text: "Name: " + model.named + "does not work"}
        //Text { text: "Name: " + named + "does not work"}

    }
  }
  ListModel{
      id: fruitModel
      ListElement { named: "Appley" }
      ListElement { named: "Orangie" }
      ListElement { named: "Bananananee" }
      ListElement { named: "Sure" }

  }

  }
```

...

Comment: I see you have been inspired by the [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) ;-) Inside the Tile>Text you should use the roleName `named` instead of `modelData`

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question.  tried that variation and since edited the question.  In the note doc..  That repeater is found within a component and uses a property from the parent model.  This repeater is inside a delegate model and uses a separate model. Placing the Text element outside the Tile works..  However, wrapped by the Tile the Text element cannot accessible the model.

Comment: I tried your code with Qt 5.11.3 (yeah I know) and all works, your variant and my variant (I get a Apple Cider text with 4 yellow rectangles, each with one of the 4 fruits). I only removed the `anchors.top: modelyData.bottom` because that is not in the question

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this question.  Using 5_15_2 I have made one variation which works too(more of a workaround)  Within the 'Tile', dropping the 'required' from 'property Item dragParent' and viola.  My humble guess.. the compiler is optimizing out something important.  ATM I'll leave the question un-edited

Comment: yes, I also had to ditch the 'required', but assumed you where using Qt6 or so. Could be related in strange way indeed